# What are the effects of DRM on Assassin's Creed 2?

Tags: pc, assassins-creed-2, drm

I was thinking to buy **Asssassin's Creed 2** for PC, but I heard  some bad voices about the DRM included in the game.

At home I have an ADSL connection but unfortunately is not really reliable. It often happens that goes down even for an hour or more.

Usually during this time a play single player games but,in Assassin's Creed 2, what happen if:

1. my internet connection **is down**. Can I launch the game and can I save the progress?
2. my internet connection **goes down** while I am playing. Can I continue to play and save the progress?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I have several other UbiSoft games that use this very same DRM, but not Assassin's Creed 2.  Here's what happens in those other games when I lose internet connectivity.

1. The game inexplicably freezes with no error message.
2. After several moments (I'd guess about 1 - 2 minutes) a message finally appears on the screen telling me that "UbiSoft's servers have become unreachable".
3. After another few seconds, if you still can't contact UbiSoft's servers, the game drops you to your Windows desktop and all unsaved progress to that point is lost.

To be clear, it doesn't have to be YOUR internet connection that fails.  It could also be a problem on UbiSoft's end, or anywhere in between.  The game only cares about being able to contact UbiSoft's servers, it doesn't care whose fault it is.

To be fair, I've played A LOT of the latest Settlers game and only been kicked out maybe five times.  However, much like with the early days of Steam, the first few days of actually owning Settlers 7 I couldn't play it at all, because UbiSoft's DRM servers were under heavy load and wouldn't authenticate my game.

I would not recommend buying a game with this type of DRM, and had I known the games I bought had this DRM, I would not have bought them.  I will never buy a game with this type of DRM again.

Comment: I'm actually boycotting all of the ubisoft games on the PC as long as they keep this kind of DRM, sad, but required.

Comment: @hokiecsgrad Unfortunately this type of DRM seems not suitable with my connection problem. I avoid to buy it. Thank you for the explanation.

Comment: Forgotten sands also has this DRM. Well it's "better" than the one in AC2. But whatever they do, pirates crack the DRM and the legit customers have to pay the price. :(

Comment: @alexanderpas: I'm usually scoff at anti-DRM boycotts on games (Spore, the MW2 LAN thing), but in this case, so am I. Sadly, Ubisoft are likely to use it as an excuse to stop producing PC games if it is successful, rather than to stop adding punishing DRM.

Comment: Ubsoft stops producing PC games, competitors pick up the stuff, no harm done (which non-big-name uses ubi?)

Comment: Its sad that Ubisoft installed this kind of a DRM mechanism but its still way better than starforce. It broke my DVD drive.

Answer (score 3):

1. You **can't** play the game.
2. You could lose your progress.

One of the requirements of the game is **constant internet connection** (which is total bonkers, if you ask me).

Comment: +1, I won't buy games that require this, I say fight piracy another way (online playing, perks, etc), not penalizing paying customers like this. That is also why I won't buy settlers 7

Answer (score 3):

Assassin's creed DRM (as well as settlers 7's, and probably all of Ubisoft's future games) work doing some calculations in the server, in the hope of rendering cracks useless.

This makes it obviously impossible to play without an internet connection (even though it doesn't even work, so *illegal owners* of the game can play it better than *paying customers*, as using an emulator they can play offline).

Comment: I'd recommend not buying from them until they remove this useless and damaging protection